# MS Project 2010 task calendar not working

Tags: ms-project, pm-software, scheduling, ms-project-2010

I've created a task calendar for certain transports that can only occur on Wednesdays, with only Wednesdays marked as working time. But when I apply that calendar to the transport milestone items, MS Project is ignoring the task calendar and scheduling the item immediately after its predecessor instead of waiting until the next possible Wednesday. For example, one is showing as scheduled for Tues Jan 30th, another for Mon March 20th.

The problem persists even if I change them from milestones to 1-day tasks, and also when I created a new task calendar (new base calendar) and applied it to the items. I need to be able to change predecessor durations and leveling delay on the fly and show the true schedule impact without messing around with constraints.

Any ideas?

Comment: Should work with 1-day duration.  Check to confirm your calendar works on a simple test project.  (I typically use similar constructs for similar reasons - i.e. if a 1-day slip causes you to miss a delivery window, the consequences can be a lot more than 1 day.)

Comment: Thanks Tom! I tried with different durations last night and it didn't work, but tried again this morning and it did. *shrug* chalk it up to the observer effect.

Comment: Thanks to Tom Boyle's comment, I was able to make it work - apparently the task calendars don't apply to milestones, only to tasks with duration.

Comment: @Zandra You or Tom Boyle could answer that question and then it can be checked and won't pop up in the Unanswered-section anymore. Just saying :)